# how to set scale and size in np.random.exponential

Tags: python, numpy, random, distribution, exponential

How can I implement this:

> Stock loss error is modelled as a renewal process that occurs between
>   time intervals. The time intervals are based on an exponential
>   distribution with a mean time between stock loss events (TBSLE). The
>   frequency of stock loss occurrence is the reciprocal of TBSLE. The
>   expected value for the mean stock loss quantity can be estimated as
>   2.05.

I tried to implement it like this, but I don't know how to set scale and size in exponential or if this approach is correct.

```
def stockLossError(self):
    stockLossErrorProbability = 0
    inverseLambda = 0.5
    errors = 0

    randomnumber = np.random.exponential(inverseLambda,none)
    if(randomnumber > stockLossErrorProbability):
        self.daysSinceLastError += 1
        self.errors += 2.05
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like the [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html) say

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(42)
>>> np.random.exponential(scale=4, size=(2, 3))
array([[  1.87707236,  12.04048572,   5.26698277],
       [  3.65177022,   0.67849948,   0.67838517]])
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have a better understanding how the exponential function works!